# swift swipe tableview cell set image with trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt AND editActionsForRowAt

Tags: uitableview, swipe

swipe table view cell then show some option to delete and edit. I want to set full image. I have seen lots of demo code but then are with text and background image, I have need to create with whole image  here is my code for ios 10 and ios 11 but I cant get success

with **editActionsForRowAt** Problem is image is repeate multiple time

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
    {


            let ArchiveAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "          ") { (action , indexPath ) -> Void in



                 tableView.setEditing(false, animated: false)
            }

            let shareAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.default, title: "          ") { (action , indexPath) -> Void in

                tableView.setEditing(false, animated: false)
            }

            ArchiveAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "archiver.png")!)
            shareAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "bloquear.png")!)


            return [ArchiveAction,shareAction]

    }
```

with **trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt** Problem is image not show properly. show white image

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

        let action =  UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "sdfsdf", handler: { (action,view,completionHandler ) in
            //do stuff
            completionHandler(true)
        })
       // action.image = UIImage(named: "archiver.png")

        action.backgroundColor = .black
        let confrigation = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
         confrigation.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = true // default is false
        return confrigation
    }
```

Please give me any solution

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the problem of a white rectangle instead of the image when using **.jpg**. Using a **.png** worked for me.

Since you are using a *.png* already, did you try to load the image name without the *.png* extension?  (*"archiver"* instead of *"archiver.png"*)

Because the parameter description of `init?(named name: String)` says:

... For PNG images, *you may omit the filename extension*. For all other file formats, always include the filename extension.